# what is session.load used for

Tags: sql, hibernate

the load of session seems to be useless,if I need to create a pojo,why i need to use load to create a object that will not be callable?

```
@Test
public void testTwoSession() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Teacher t = (Teacher) session.load(Teacher.class, 2);
    System.out.println(t);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

before the commit,the object will be printed,but when the session is committed,the print operation will fail.now I am wondering why not just use get method to get the Teacher object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"`session.load()`" is not useless, it is a very per-formant operation in many situations. The difference between "`load`" and "`get`" is that "`load`" creates a so called "**proxy**", which is a temporary hibernate object that does not actually read the DB. On the contrary the "`get`" method always reads the actual data (if it does not exists it returns null).

In your scenario it will not make such a big difference (`load()` and `get()` will both read the object), but imagine a scenario where you want to do an insert in a row. In that case you will have the "`load()`" doing "1 insert" and the "`get()`" doing "1 read" + "1 insert".

Comment: load() won't check if the object exists. In your scenario, you will get an exception at flush time if the object doesn't exist if you have a foreign key constraint in the database.

Comment: but I may write a interface like the following `Teacher findTeacher(int id);`,but the session is close after I commit.that is,I can never use load method to implement this interface.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right, there is no check, only the exception "ObjectNotFoundException".

Comment: @ssj this method's goal is to load the teacher state from the database. In this case, get() is the appropriate method (or a fetching query if you need to load state of other associated entities). Just because for this case load() isn't appropriate doesn't make it useless for all the other cases.

Comment: can you find a scenario that load used for?

Comment: There are many examples on the web, look at this for example: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/

Comment: @ssj: both answers give you a scenario where it's useful. Have you read the answers?

Answer (score 0):

The `load()` method is mainly useful when you just want a reference to an entity, but don't actually care about its state, for example when you just want to attach this entity to another one:

```
public void createMessageForSender(String text, String senderId) {
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setText(text);
    Sender sender = (Sender) session.load(Sender.class, senderId);
    message.setSender(sender);
    session.persist(message);
}
```

In the above code, you need a Sender entity reference to create the new Message entity, but you don't care about its state, and don't need to load it from the database. `load()` is thus useful.

Comment: but if you close the session after load,that means the Sender can not do anything.it may case a mistake that you will not find.

Comment: I don't get you. As soon as you close the session, if you have non-loaded lazy-loaded entities and associations, navigating through them will cause an exception. But you won't load the whole database each time just in case the caller might need it. So, if you don't need the state, you don't load it. And if you need it, you load it. As simple as that. In my example, the caller can't even get any reference to the message nor its sender, so why would I load the sender state?